# «Редко когда» — нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, словосочетания

Возникли трудности с данным предложением.
*Только вот отчего-то заглядывать в ее темно-серые глаза в последнее время он **редко(,) когда** решался.*

Comment: https://phraseology.academic.ru/5465/Редко_когда

Comment: @oleedd  А теперь про стилистику предложения что-нибудь скажите.

Comment: @Sharon Вы к стилистике придираетесь, только когда не надо. А когда реально ошибка — вам нравится.

Comment: А вам все нравится? Я просто спросила.

Comment: @Sharon Прямо ошибок здесь нет. Редактировать можно, только если есть ошибки.

Comment: @Sharon Если "отчего-то" не звучит, замените на "почему-то".

Comment: Так редактировать же нельзя...)

Comment: @Sharon Ой, ещё думал написать, но подумал, что сами догадаетесь. У себя заменить. Для особо доходчивых: не в ответе, а в своей тетради.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [Вопрос № 212675](http://www.gramota.tv/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BE%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B0)
> Нужна ли запятая: "**Редко когда** случается одному человеку сделать это"?
> **Ответ справочной службы русского языка**
> Нет, запятая не требуется.

Предложение довольно длинное, но запятые в нем не нужны.
**Редко когда** (наречие) — это неразложимое словосочетание в значении *нечасто, когда-никогда*.

Я бы не стала ничего "изымать" из предложения или добавлять в него (один из участников форума когда-то сказал, что авторский текст надо холить и лелеять), перестроила бы чуть.
Вот так:
*Только вот отчего-то заглядывать в ее темно-серые глаза он в последнее время **редко когда** решался.*

Примеры:
*Он, правда, умер лет двести назад, так что теперь его **редко когда** встретишь* (Дмитрий Емец. Последний стожар);
*Люди **редко когда** могли позволить себе делать необычные формы из монолитного бетона* (Кир Булычев. Гостья из будущего).

А конструкция "только вот отчего-то" встречается нередко:
***Только вот отчего-то** встреченная в метро девчонка, даже имени которой не знал, не выходила из головы* (Георгий Елин. Шуточка);
***Только вот отчего-то** на сердце было неспокойно* (Лия Рой. Случайный ребенок от миллиардера).

Comment: Спасибо большое за такой развернутый и полезный ответ, вы очень мне помогли!:)

Comment: Приветствую Вас на сайте, Дарья! Рада, если действительно помогла.

Answer (score 0):

Только вот отчего-то заглядывать в ее темно-серые глаза в последнее время он редко - явно не достает глагола. Это примыкание вроде называется, когда наречия связаны с глаголом. Редко связано с решался, редко решался - он редко решался, он заглядывать - тоже явно не звучит. Когда тоже входит в наречное выражение, видимо - редко когда. Выглядит как запутанное сложносочиненное:

*Только вот отчего-то заглядывать в ее темно-серые глаза в последнее время,(но) он редко когда решался*.

Первоначально эта фраза могла звучать так:

*Только вот отчего-то заглядывал в ее темно-серые глаза в последнее время, когда он редко решался...*

Ладно, мои заморочки, нет тут сложноподчиненного: он редко решался заглядывать, - просто инверсия кучи глаголов связанных с он, образующих одно и тоже составное сказуемое:

*Только вот отчего-то заглядывать в ее темно-серые глаза в последнее время он редко когда решался.*

или

*Только вот отчего-то он редко когда решался заглядывать в ее темно-серые глаза в последнее время.*

Comment: *Заглядывал, когда он редко решался* — как новый мем бессвязности речи.

Comment: есть такое)....

Comment: Но я бы подчеркнул, что заглядывал и он решался - это не одно и тоже) заглядывал - кто-то, а решался он. Иначе зачем такой забор городить) Пусть уж будет полная дисперсия сознания)

Comment: *Решался заглядывать...* С придаточным такой смысл не сделать.

Answer (score 0):

Я  бы так написала: ***Но вот заглядывать в ее темно-серые глаза / он теперь редко когда решался.***

Это другая форма для похожего содержания (как я его поняла). Хочется, чтобы каждое слово имело **точный и нужный смысл,** а лишних слов не было.  Это касается и присоединительных союзов, и выбора местоимений, а также необходимости в таких местоимениях.

Также **порядок** слов простом предложении должен быть соответствующим (актуальное членение предложения). При чтении оно должно делиться на две части (тема и рема).

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148849/discussion-on-answer-by-sharon------); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.